# Using ArcGIS Pro to measure change in land use over time (dynamically evolving maps)

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-rest-api, time-series, land-use, change-detection

How can I use ArcGIS Pro to record change in land use over time?

I am working with this [landuse dataset](https://maps.london.gov.uk/gla/rest/services/IMA/IMA_context_information_landuse/MapServer/1) for London. I would like to know what use any given polygon was being put to each year between 2000 and 2020. I have two tasks that I need to complete.

First, I need to check whether the [linked data](https://maps.london.gov.uk/gla/rest/services/IMA/IMA_context_information_landuse/MapServer/1) contains the time-varying information that would allow me to track the evolution of each polygon over time.

Second, if the dataset does include such time-varying information, I need to analyze this change.

Does ArcGIS Pro have functionality that would allow me to conduct these two steps?

Comment: When you say "ArcGIS" do you mean ArcGIS Pro, ArcMap or another part of that platform?  At the moment your two links seem to be broken.  Also, as per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.  I recommend reviewing http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115 for tips on how to structure a good question.

Comment: Thanks for checking. I have fixed the links. The product I am using is Pro.

Comment: Have you been able to display that dataset in ArcGIS Pro?  If so, describing the steps you used to do it may help to attract a potential answerer to your question.  Also, you still seem to be asking two unmarked questions.  If you're stuck trying "to check whether the linked data contains the time-varying information" then I think that's what you should focus this question on.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/image-analyst/the-change-detection-wizard.htm